# Cannot locate gcc-9-base and libgcc-9-dev with a linux terminal on a chromebook with debian

Tags: debian

Hi I'm trying to install BEEF from github but it keeps saying cannot locate gcc-9-base and libgcc-9-dev. Again im using a linux terminal on a chromebook if that changes anything. I've never used a linux terminal before. Haven't seen a question about this with someones computer as a chromebook.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the answer would be to install the package build-essentials on a Debian system. It includes, I believe, both of those components.

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

However, if the package truly needs gcc-9, then things are much more complicated. At the moment Chromebook Linux (Crostini) is based on Debian Buster, that comes with gcc-8. You would either have to manually upgrade to Debian Bullseye or find gcc-9 ported to Debian Buster to compile BEEF. Note that BEEF seems to have other dependencies as well that need to be installed.